Will CO2 dissolved in water change the tds reading of the water?
I have filtered water reading between 0 and 4 ppm on a tds meter.  I add CO2 using a soda stream.  The water reads 27-34 ppm after adding CO2.
Is the change in tds readings due to the CO2 or due to impurities in my CO2?

TDS meters measure conductivity assuming NaCl is the solute. Since CO2 is acidic in water it adds ions and registers.  Curious .what contaminants do you suspect in the CO2 source? Also the oxidation to CO2 is to measure total organic carbon [TOC] not to measure TDS.

@jimchmst ty. I'm using a tds meter.

@jimchmst ty. I'm using a tds meter. I didn't expect any contaminants but I purchased the CO2 from a new source.  I can't put my finger on it but it tastes different than what I got from the old source.

@Poutnik I'm measuring with a tds pen.
